# How can I add graphics.h library on my mac?

Tags: c, macos, libraries, bgi

I want to draw a rectangle using a C program. So I was trying to use the `graphics.h` header. But the GCC compiler gave me a error saying that the library could not be found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`graphics.h` is a header that define functions for [**libbgi**](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/) (Borland Graphics Interface)

Unless you have a Borland compiler of some sort installed on your Mac (if that's even possible), I think you'll end up having to use other graphic libraries, or install a Windows/Linux Virtual Machine on your Mac and then run/compile your code inside it.

Answer (score 2):

`graphics.h` is not a standard C header and is probably a part of a custom library.  If you can track down that original library and provide more info, we can probably help you get it set up.

Comment: thanks. where should i start looking for that? I've been trying to find the gcc libraries but with no success.