# What can I use instead of #include<graphics.h> in Mac Os?

Tags: c, macos, include, bgi

The question is the same above.

Since when I compile my C program it gives me a fatal error (graphics.h not found), I was wondering what I can use instead of it.

Consider that I DO NOT WANT links to other sites or whatever, because I'm a newbie and I wouldn't understand.

I just need the command to type, in order to make it work. If I have to download a library then it's fine, provided you guide me all through the process.

Thanks.

**Here is what I am trying to compile**

A code to create a smiley.

```
#include <graphics>

int main(void)
{
int midX, midY,
leftEyeX, rightEyeX, eyeY,
noseX, noseY,
headRadius,
eyeNoseRadius,
smileRadius,
stepX, stepY,

initwindow(500, 400, "Happy Face - press key to close", 200, 150);

midX = getmaxx() / 2;
midY = getmaxy() / 2;
headRadius = getmaxy() / 4;
circle(midX, midY, headRadius);

stepX = headRadius / 4;
stepY = stepX;
leftEyeX = midX - stepX;
eyeY = midY - stepY;
eyeNoseRadius = headRadius / 10;
circle(leftEyeX, eyeY, eyeNoseRadius);
circle(rightEyeX, eyeY, eyeNoseRadius);

noseX = midX;
noseY = midY + stepY;
circle(noseX, noseY, eyeNoseRadius);

smileRadius = (int)(0.75*headRadius + 0.5);
arc(midX, midY, 210, 330, smileRadius);

getch();
closegraph();

return(0);

}
```

Comment: What are you hoping to gain from `graphics.h`? Is there some API / library that you're hoping to use? It would be worth mentioning it in your question.

Comment: `<graphics.h>` is just a random filename - we need more of a clue.  Why do you think you need it?  Please choose C or C++

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm writing in C!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i add graphics.h library on my mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881649/how-can-i-add-graphics-h-library-on-my-mac)

Comment: @AlanTuring then why did you add C++ tag to your question?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Useless.

Comment: @Attie Useless.

Comment: @AlanTuring No... your question is useless - do you even know what you're trying to accomplish by including `graphics.h`?

Comment: @Attie Your useless link does not provide me any help or information. Do you want me to write here all the code I'm trying to compile?

Comment: @AlanTuring a concise example, yes. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AttieDone! The code is above!

Comment: Did you find that code in a museum? I'm pretty sure I recognise those function calls. From 25 years ago from Borland compilers. The way we speak to hardware and the operating system changes over the years. You can't expect to use a library that worked on one compiler for DOS to work on something more modern. If you want that to work, you need to dig up a compiler and operating system that's equally old as the code you're trying to run.

Comment: I got curious. I wasn't that far off with 25 years ago (since that was when I used it). The last product that supported that graphics interface was Borland C++ 5.02 which was released in 1997.

Comment: @Art lol, well I was trying to follow some programs written on the book of Hanly and Koffman "problem solving and programming in C" but it says its from 2013... not that old! o.o

Comment: @AlanTuring Sounds like they just keep reprinting an old book without updating it to more modern interfaces. Or maybe there exists a compatibility layer somewhere that simulates the old Borland Graphics Interface on some more modern compilers. There is no graphics interface that will work on all operating systems. The closest you can get is OpenGL or SDL. You can google tutorials for those. Or wait a bit until you learn more and stay with text output for now.

Comment: BGI graphics were still used until the late 1990s, but then mostly for student purposes, as professionals were then moving over to Windows graphics.

Comment: @Art The problem is: how to write a "modern" code for that?

Comment: [Find out what each BGI function does](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/) and replace with similar functions from modern library. Or use [wrapper library](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/) with your modern library (note: I haven't used linked library).

Answer (score 8):

`graphics.h` refers to the non-standard graphics library called BGI, designed by Borland in the year 1989 to be used with Borland compilers for the MS DOS operative system. It is not C standard, it is not portable. It cannot be used on any other system than DOS or early 32 bit Windows (95/98 etc), unless you use emulators.

If you wasted time learning about BGI, you were scammed by your teacher/school. 
As a beginner, you should forget all about MS DOS graphics and focus on things that are actually used in the real world, in the year 2017.

Comment: The problem is: how to write a "modern" code for that?

Comment: @AlanTuring Depends on OS, toolchain, graphics library etc, but also what kind of graphics you want to make: user interfaces or 3D stuff.