# Computer Graphics in mac

Tags: bgi

I have to learn **computer graphics**, but in my **macbook-air** libraries like **conio.h, graphics.h** are not working. What should I do to run it without problem??

Comment: conio.h isn't available on *nix, so you'd need to somehow run a Windows ARM install on an emulator.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808059/what-can-i-use-instead-of-includegraphics-h-in-mac-os

Answer (score 0):

The `<graphics.h>` is the part of turbo C, It's a very old library and now is deprecated.
The `<conio.h>` is only in Windows, and it's not directly related to computer graphics.

I recommend you to use some graphics libraries for starting learning, like [OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/).